# azure storage queue message live time

Tags: azure-storage, azure-queues

Did I understood it right that in Windows Azure Queue storage a message can live for 7 days maximum?

What happens with the message after 7 days?

What happens with the message if you read it once during the 7 days and you don't delete it? I mean you read the message from the queue and set the visibility timeout to let's say 1 minute. What happens after you have read the message (without deleting it) and the 1 minutes timeout visibility expires? I know is back and available on the queue but what happens with the 7 days TTL of that message, is it renewed to 7 days from that point or is 7 days totally since message was created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you understood it correctly. Messages from queues are deleted automatically within 7 days time and there is nothing called 're-newed'. Once inserted into the queue *storage*, it will be deleted automatically and there is no way you can recover it back(there are no recovery tools either).

Answer (score 20):

You can now opt-in to infinite TTL for Azure Storage Queue messages by specifying an expiry time of -1 seconds when initially queuing the message.

> The time-to-live interval for the message, in seconds. Prior to version 2017-07-29, the maximum time-to-live allowed is 7 days. For version 2017-07-29 or later, the maximum time-to-live can be any positive number, as well as -1 indicating that the message does not expire. If this parameter is omitted, the default time-to-live is 7 days.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message#uri-parameters

Comment: This might be a more relevant link?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message#uri-parameters

"Specifies the time-to-live interval for the message, in seconds. Prior to version 2017-07-29, the maximum time-to-live allowed is 7 days. For version 2017-07-29 or later, the maximum time-to-live can be any positive number, as well as -1 indicating that the message does not expire. If this parameter is omitted, the default time-to-live is 7 days."

Comment: Depending on the method you use to add the queue message, some methods like the CloudQueue AddMessageAsync require a type of `TimeSpan` for the TTL so you can't just supply -1.  In this case, you can achieve a functionally equivalent result with `TimeSpan.MaxValue`

Comment: The way to set the time to live to infinite using the C# SDK, which also expects a TimeSpan, is to use TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1)

Answer (score 3):

When adding a message, users specify a time to live (< 7 days) after which the message is automatically deleted if it still exists in the queue.

Maybe you need to use Windows Azure Service Bus Queue. Take a look at a great comparison between the two Queues available at Azure:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Link :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message#uri-parameters

I think earlier never expire option was not there but, now you can add **messagettl=-1** *to make it never expire*

[Messgae TTL Azure Storage Queue Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XHBZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes 7 day is maximum. There is feedback feature request here . You can go and comment

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/4134167-infinite-ttl-for-queue-messages