# Setting the TTL for Azure Queue items moved to poison queue

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have a Storage Account where the creation of a blob triggers an Event Grid subscription to move a `BlobCreated` event to a queue. After that a Function App is triggered on the queue, which will fail on corrupt documents thus moving the queue item to a poison queue.

Right now it seems to move them using the default 7 day TTL, but for the poison queue I would like a TTL for forever. Is there any way to change the TTL for the poison queue in the trigger function?

What I've tried so far:

1. Looking if the Event Grid subscription had any options to set the TTL for the queue
2. Looking for possible options in the `host.json` file (in Func App)
3. Using reflection to change the `ExpirationTime` in the `CloudQueueMessage` input desperately hoping it might be used to create the poison queue item

Answer (score 1):

> Right now it seems to move them using the default 7 day TTL, but for
> the poison queue I would like a TTL for **forever**. Is there any way
> to change the TTL for the poison queue in the trigger function?

You can set them as -1.
There's more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602781/1138731) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet). You'll need to manually handle these.
You could easily add a listener to the poison queue and re send the message with the TTL of -1.

**UPDATE**

Looked further into this. You can implement a custom `IQueueProcessorFactory` that returns a CustomQueueProcessor. The default implementation is [here.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Queues/QueueProcessor.cs)
You can change the way the poison queues are handled and send the TTL of -1.

Comment: Thanks, I've considered the same but it's more of a workaround than a solution. It'll also triple the requests for the poison queue and require more custom code to maintain.

Comment: The `IQueueProcessorFactory` sounds good, although all reference material I can find on implementing (adding it to the configuration) is for Web Jobs and not Function Apps.

Comment: @404 I know, it's a little bit unfortunate/misleading, but Azure Functions use the underlying Azure Webjobs assemblies. Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.